# Display Messagebox Buttons / Icon as an integer

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to display a Message Box with both an icon and buttons using only integers / strings. This is VERY simple to do in VB6 (but I want to do it in c#); below is an example.

```
Call Msgbox("Message Text","Message Title", 32, 64)
```

As far as C# goes... I know I can declare something as type 'MessageButtons' but I don't want to do that, I am looking for some way to represent the messagebutton as an integer (or as a string). Either one will work just fine.

In short, how can I convert the above code to c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is to have 2 arrays which you fill with the corresponding buttons/icons...

Something like this:

```
MessageBoxButtons[] mbs = new[] {
    MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore,
    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
    MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel,
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel
};

MessageBoxIcon[] mbi = new[] {
    MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk,
    MessageBoxIcon.Error,
    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
    MessageBoxIcon.Hand,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information,
    MessageBoxIcon.None,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question,
    MessageBoxIcon.Stop,
    MessageBoxIcon.Warning
};

MessageBox.Show("Message Text", "Message Title", mbs[2], mbi[4]);
```

But as I can see there is a different set between vb6 and c# 4.0 I am using... so you have to figure out how you want to translate them

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do, again - not sure if it's even possible.  If not, I will use your method and mark it as the correct answer in this case.

  /* Int32 myint = 0;
            myint = (Int32)MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore;
            MessageBox.Show(myint.ToString());
            */

           MessageBox.Show("Testing", "Title", 2, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

Comment: I ended up using your method after a simple conversion to c#.net. All is working fine on my end. Thank you very much (answer marked as correct).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show

Google is a friend =). That link is the fourth result for "c# message boxes".

You will ask Google many questions such as this while learning a programming language.

```
DialogResult result3 = MessageBox.Show(
            "Title",
            "The Question",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2
);
```

To use integers as arguments, look through the docs for the value of `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel`, MessageBoxIcon.Question, etc...

Comment: I have read through that document many times before asking this question - I guess I just failed to fully comprehend it. I will go and take a second look and report back here shortly.

Comment: Perhaps I am still not understanding this document, or perhaps you did not completely understand my question - but I do not want to use "Messageboxbuttons.YesNoCancel", rather I would like to use an integer value which represents this button style.

Thank you.